# Can I ask a question regarding a programming languages documentation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question regarding how to interpret / invoke a method found in Apples Swift Developer documentation.

Can I ask a question regarding a programming languages documentation on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I've asked my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226888/how-do-i-invoke-a-method-found-in-apple-developer-reference-documentation

Comment: I've left a comment on your linked post. The question (as you actually posted it) IMO is **not** appropriate for SO, because it's far too vague. My comment (to your SO post) explains why.

Comment: @KenWhite I disagree. Unless there is no rhyme or reason to documentation at all, there has to be a methodical process to finding what you need and seeing what it takes to invoke it.

Comment: There certainly is - it's specified in the documentation, as are the standards used for that documentation. If you can't read it there, why would you be able to read it at SO? The *methodical process* is *read the documentation, including the standards that are followed (and explained) in it*, and then look at examples if the documentation isn't clear to see how it's done.

Comment: You might have some luck at *Ask Different*, but I'm not 100% sure if it would be on-topic. From the help center: **Code-level programming questions (cocoa, LLVM, etc…) are off-topic here, however we do allow AppleScript, Automator, and UNIX shell scripting questions like "How to use homebrew"**

Comment: How terrible *are* the Swift docs?  I'm sure they're covered under fifteen layers of NDA bullshit, but if you added an example to your question taken directly from these docs perhaps someone can pull it apart and demonstrate how it applies to actual code?  If you're actually afraid of Apple's stupid NDAs, you could rewrite a document for a method to make it nonsensical. They can't possibly be NDA-ing the *format* of their documents as well as the contents, right?

Comment: That was my initial thought @Will. I did add an example in my original question. I think it confused people and they just tried showing me working examples of the method without explaining how they arrived at it... so I removed the example.

Comment: Did you post an example from the docs then show your (incorrect) interpretation? That way people could possibly see where your disconnect is.  Describing your thought process on the interpretation would be advisable as well.

Comment: I showed my attempt, perhaps I shouldve explained my thought processes more. Either way, I completely understand why the question was confusing and why it got put on hold. I think i just need to spend more time  in the docs and that's all there is to it. No silver bullet answer.

Comment: The rabidity of SO members regarding Apple's NDAs is obscuring your view, @Will. The [docs are freely available](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) for your copy-pasting pleasure.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm informing Apple you've violated your NDA.  Some NDA, at least.  NDA ALL THE THINGS!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Such questions would be *on-topic*. So yes, you can ask them.

Be **very** clear on what part of the documentation you don't understand and show your research, as these kind of questions can easily be construed as having a lack of effort. Otherwise, go ahead!

Comment: Thanks Bradly, my post is ready to submit but after reading your answer. Maybe I'll make another attempt at understanding the documents.